# Show in progress label until the operation finished

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a button and a label on my UI. When i clicks on the button i want to show "In Progress" on the label until the for loop finished and then again the same label should show the result of the collection.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  label1.Content = "In progress..";          
  List<string> intList = new List<string>();
  for (long i = 0; i <= 50000000; i++)
  {
    intList.Add("Test");
  }
  label1.Content = intList.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are having with the code in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to [farm the work out to a background thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff959203.aspx), otherwise your loop continues on the UI thread hence you see no "progress".

You can use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) or a [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235608) to accomplish this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Content = "In progress..";
    Task.Factory.StartNew<List<string>>(
    () =>
    {
        List<string> intList = new List<string>();
        for (long i = 0; i <= 50000000; i++)
        {
            intList.Add("Test");
        }

        return intList;
    })
    .ContinueWith(
        (t) => label1.Content = t.Result.ToString(),
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Comment: Hi, i am getting an exception when i tried to use your code "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew<TResult>(System.Func<TResult>)'"

Comment: @user1399377: the code could be pregnant, instead it should be `Task.Factory`.

Comment: No its not working again getting the exception, Please help to get me a solution. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @sixlettervariables, i used backgroundworker and now it is working as per my expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [background worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to do your actual work (the for loop) and subscribe to the event he raises when his function completes. You can also check progress etc for a more valuable progress meter.

Answer (score 0):

You should do that with BackgroundWorker. Here it seems nice example of how to do that.
http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/03/wpf-multithreading-using-the-backgroundworker-and-reporting-the-progress-to-the-ui/